# Getting error "Provider com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found" in unit test but not in main program

Tags: c#, unit-testing, webclient, htmlunit

I am building an application in C# which uses com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient to access and retrieve information from webpages.

My application runs fine from the main project but when I try to build unit tests to test the project classes I get the following error:

```
FactoryConfigurationError
Message "Provider com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found"
Source  "IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.API"  string
StackTrace  "   at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.loadConfiguration(Reader configurationReader)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.loadConfiguration()
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration..ctor(BrowserVersion )
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.getInstance(BrowserVersion browserVersion)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine..ctor(WebClient webClient)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.init(BrowserVersion , ProxyConfig )
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient..ctor(BrowserVersion browserVersion)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient..ctor()
at GWT.HeadlessBrowser..ctor() in C:\\hg\\EXE\\GWT\\HeadlessBrowser.cs:line 57
at TestGWT.ProgramTest.TestLogInProcessForGWT() in C:\\hg\\TestGWT\\ProgramTest.cs:line 115"
```

Trying to create a HtmlUnit WebClient in the unit test class causes this error as well.

I have project references htmlunit-2.7, IKVM.OpenJDK.Core, and IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.API in both the main project and the project containing the unit test.

Do I need an additional project reference for the unit test to run? What might be causing this error?

The test class uses Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

Comment: Katie did the answer resolve your problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ran into the same issue just recently while testing the same library.  I found that including a reference to IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.Parse.dll solved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I hit a similar problem.

It seems the com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl class is not loaded and so the factory can not create it. Adding this line in before the call to the factory forces the assembly to load, and then the factory can see it and everything works as expected...

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.@internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl s =   new  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.@internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl();
```

Comment: Adding this code work fine. VB.Net Dim s As com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl = New com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl()